# Añadir action a formulario PHP a través de Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

soy algo novato en Javascript y PHP, verán tengo un formulario sencillo en PHP que envía los datos por método POST y hace un action hacia una página "calculadoraPost.php" que recibe los datos introducidos y posteriormente envía un correo, hasta aquí funciona todo genial, el problema surge cuando tengo un script de javascript que necesita esos datos por POST para funcionar (Es un tema de enviar automáticamente los datos introducidos del formulario a una hoja de cálculo de Google sheets), lo primero que se me ocurrió es quitar el action del formulario y tratar de hacerlo desde el mismo script, una vez este haga su función con los datos, pero no me funciona el script recibe correctamente los datos por POST y los procesa (Los guarda en la hoja de cálculo correctamente) pero al realizar el action con **document.forms['miform'].action** desde el script para continuar a enviar el correo no funciona. Espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Muchas gracias.

```
  const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxoozkPrIpsP4t6flTu5TKu37btWQnPQg1ymd1Y2zN0lUnlShU/exec'    
  const form = document.forms['miform']form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
  .then(response => document.forms['miform'].action="../wp-content/themes/jupiter/calculadoraPost.php")
  .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
```

})

Comment: No entendí tu pregunta. ¿Por qué dices que quieres cambiar el `action` del formulario? ¿qué sentido tendría hacerlo y en qué te ayuda eso a resolver el problema?

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.getElementById("id_de_tu_formulario").action = "/fichero.php";
```

Eso te deberia de ir si lo poner en la funcion de un boton

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, la idea era quitarlo porque aunque esté en el formulario no lo hace, al darle clic al botón enviar sé queda sin hacer nada, lo único que si hace es ingresar los datos en la hoja de Google, pero no hace caso al action, entonces pensé en colocarlo de alguna manera en el script js que hace la tarea de ingresar esos datos que también haga el action pero no me funciona , no sé si me explico muy bien, gracias de antemano.